# Averaging four, three and two years value

Tags: average, temperature

I want to calculate average of every four years temperature, three years, and two years before 2008: starting from 2004 to 2020.
For four years: temperature average of 2004 to 2007, then average of 2005-2008, then average 2006-2009, until 2017-2020.
For three years: average of 2005-2007, then average of 2006-2008, then average of 2007-2009, until 2018-2020.
And so on, the same pattern for 2 years.

I don't have any single try to be honest because I don't know the keywords to get into it. I do apologize. Could you please help me how to do this in R? Thank you in advance.